# is there any way to find all the occurrence of a pattern in a text instead of finding the first occurrence in Boyer Moore algorithm

Tags: java, boyer-moore

I'm working on Boyer Moore string matching algorithm in java so it could work on Arabic text sufficiently, I have the code that finds the first occurrence of a pattern instead of all occurrence.

I tried to modify to it but it doesn't work, I got arrayIndexoutofbounds exception.
the exception I got is :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   -1    at BM.findPattern(BM.java:27)   at BM.main(BM.java:110)

the purpose is to modify the algorithm so it can handle the vocalized Arabic Text.
here is a sample of input and out put:
Enter Text

anananananana

Enter Pattern

ana
found at postion 0
then I got the exception above

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;


   /** Class BoyerMoore **/
 public class BM
 {
    /** function findPattern **/
    public void findPattern(String t, String p)
    {
        char[] text = t.toCharArray();
        char[] pattern = p.toCharArray();

        int pos = indexOf(text, pattern);
        if (pos == -1)
            System.out.println("\nNo Match\n");
        else
            System.out.println("Pattern found at position : "+ pos);



    }
    /** Function to calculate index of pattern substring **/
    public int indexOf(char[] text, char[] pattern) 
    {
        if (pattern.length == 0) 
            return 0;
        int charTable[] = makeCharTable(pattern);
        int offsetTable[] = makeOffsetTable(pattern);
        for (int i = pattern.length - 1, j; i < text.length;) 
        {
            for (j = pattern.length - 1; pattern[j] == text[i]; --i, --j) 
                     if (j == 0) 
                    return i;

              // i += pattern.length - j; // For naive method
              i += Math.max(offsetTable[pattern.length - 1 - j], 
        charTable[text[i]]);
        }
        return -1;
      }
      /** Makes the jump table based on the mismatched character 
       information **/
      private int[] makeCharTable(char[] pattern) 
      {
        final int ALPHABET_SIZE = 256;
        int[] table = new int[ALPHABET_SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < table.length; ++i) 
               table[i] = pattern.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length - 1; ++i) 
               table[pattern[i]] = pattern.length - 1 - i;
        return table;
      }
      /** Makes the jump table based on the scan offset which mismatch 
      occurs. **/
      private static int[] makeOffsetTable(char[] pattern) 
      {
        int[] table = new int[pattern.length];
        int lastPrefixPosition = pattern.length;
        for (int i = pattern.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) 
        {
            if (isPrefix(pattern, i + 1)) 
                   lastPrefixPosition = i + 1;
              table[pattern.length - 1 - i] = lastPrefixPosition - i + 
         pattern.length - 1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < pattern.length - 1; ++i) 
        {
              int slen = suffixLength(pattern, i);
              table[slen] = pattern.length - 1 - i + slen;
        }
        return table;
    }
    /** function to check if needle[p:end] a prefix of pattern **/
    private static boolean isPrefix(char[] pattern, int p) 
    {
        for (int i = p, j = 0; i < pattern.length; ++i, ++j) 
            if (pattern[i] != pattern[j]) 
                  return false;
        return true;
    }
    /** function to returns the maximum length of the substring ends at p and is a suffix **/
    private static int suffixLength(char[] pattern, int p) 
    {
        int len = 0;
        for (int i = p, j = pattern.length - 1; i >= 0 && pattern[i] == pattern[j]; --i, --j) 
               len += 1;
        return len;
    }
    /** Main Function **/
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {    
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Boyer Moore Algorithm Test\n");
        System.out.println("\nEnter Text\n");
        String text = br.readLine();
        System.out.println("\nEnter Pattern\n");
        String pattern = br.readLine();
        BM bm = new BM(); 
        bm.findPattern(text, pattern);     
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line is 27th in your code? It looks like something is missing in your code, there is nothing in `findPattern` that could possibly throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Or part of the stachtrace is missing.

Comment: Can you provide some sample inputs and expected outputs? It seems to be working fine so far..

Comment: cardouken, it works for the first occurrence of the pattern only.